# NginX to serve uWSGI running on another instance

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, uwsgi

Instance 1: I have uWSGI & Nginx running on an instance which can be accessed by `api.test.com`.

Instance 2: And I also have another AWS instance running uWSGI and Nginx which can be accessed by ec2-x-x-x-x.com.

I was trying to access uWSGi running in my second instance by using the first url: `api.text.com` without changing any domain name related stuff.

Initial instance 1:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.api.test.com api.test.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

Initial instance 2:

```
server {
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:5000;
    }
}
```

**Nginx and uWSGI are working perfectly fine on both instances at this point.**

**Without** modifying instance 2. Final instance 1:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.api.test.com api.test.com;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass ec2-x-x-x-x.com:80;
    }
}
```

Throws an error in instance 1 Nginx logs that upstream prematurely closed connection. Read similar problems but couldn't figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself!

Putting `uwsgi_pass ec2-x-x-x-x.com:5000;` instead of `uwsgi_pass ec2-x-x-x-x.com:80;` in modified instance 1 solved it. I put :80 because I thought request has to pass through Nginx in instance 2 but not necessary.

Moreover, Nginx in instance 2 doesn't need to run while accessing uwsgi of instance 2 from instance 1. Have to have Nginx if you want to access it from a browser like `ec2-x-x-x-x.com`.